# Text classification in pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas, text, classification

So I have a very large pandas dataframe consisting of transaction data:

```
description   amount
foo           10
bar           5
baz           9
foo bar       12
foobar        15
bar baz       20
bazbar        19
```

Expected output is as follows:

```
description   amount    tag
foo           10        foo 
bar           5         bar
baz           9         baz
foo bar       12        foo, bar
foobar        15        foobar 
bar baz       20        bar, baz
bazbar        19        bazbar
```

My thought process is as follows:

- Create a huge list of unique `words` from all rows in `df['description']`
- Then for the new column `df['tag']`, for each item in list, do a `isin` and assign the relevant tag.

I'm not sure how to create the list of unique `words`. Plus, I'm not sure this is the correct approach to solve this problem.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Why is `bazbar` categorized as `baz, bar`, and not treated as a unique word?  Same with `foobar`.

Comment: Because, I want the partial string match

Comment: Perhaps because `'baz' in 'bazbar' == True`?

Comment: Yep @AChampion is correct.

Comment: I understand that, but how do you know the partial strings, why is `bazb` not a partial string, how are you finding the "unique words"

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Okay, I've amended the expected output.

Comment: so when it comes to `foo bar`, since `foo` and `bar` are both in tags, the tags should really be `foo, ,bar`

Comment: @anishtain4 Sorry I don't get what you mean. The tags are `foo, bar`. Do you mean it should be `foo,,bar`?

Comment: How do you determine what is a tag? let's go from top in description. `foo` is not in tags, will be added, `bar` is not in tags, will be added, `baz` is not in tags, will be added, `foo bar` is not in tags, but `foo` and `bar` are in tags. So how do you decide it should be `foo, bar` instead of `foo, ,bar`?

Comment: @anishtain4 Yep I see now. I'm thinking of doing this by creating a huge list of unique words from all rows in df['description']. So these will be all the possible tags

Comment: df['tag'] = df.description.map(lambda x: ",".join(x.split()))

Comment: and how to say in that list there should be two separate tags or a single one combined. After all ` bar` is a combination of ` ` and `bar` the same way `foobar` is a combination of `foo` and `bar`

Comment: ahh, I see now that you edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['foo', 'bar', 'bas', 'foo bar', 
'foobar', 'bar baz', 'bazbar']})
a['tag'] = a.description.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.split()))
print(a)

description    tag
foo            foo
bar            bar
bas            bas
foo bar        foo, bar
foobar         foobar
bar baz        bar, baz
bazbar         bazbar
```

A `.apply(lambda...)` is a nice paradigm in pandas that will go over every row and perform a function.  Here I'm making a list out of space-delimitated words in the description column via `.split()` then converting it back into a string with a `,` separation via `.join()`

Comment: If you only want the unique tags (I didn't see an example in your example where this would flag), use `lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.split()))`